# Flask continuous integration error 30 python

Tags: flask, continuous-integration

I am trying to perform continuous integration but keep getting:

Error: Process completed with exit code 30.

```
    enter code************* Module test_routes
test/test_routes.py:46:0: C0301: Line too long (115/100) (line-too-long)
test/test_routes.py:157:0: C0301: Line too long (115/100) (line-too-long)
test/test_routes.py:191:0: C0301: Line too long (103/100) (line-too-long)
test/test_routes.py:1:0: R0401: Cyclic import (seoulbike_app -> seoulbike_app.contact_bp) (cyclic-import)
test/test_routes.py:1:0: R0401: Cyclic import (seoulbike_app -> seoulbike_app.bike_bp) (cyclic-import)
test/test_routes.py:1:0: R0401: Cyclic import (seoulbike_app -> seoulbike_app.blog_bp) (cyclic-import)
test/test_routes.py:1:0: R0401: Cyclic import (seoulbike_app -> seoulbike_app.contact_bp -> seoulbike_app.models) (cyclic-import)

-----------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 8.24/10

Error: Process completed with exit code 30. here
```

That is the last few parts of the error and I can't find any useful information in the log.

The code for the pipeline for the CI of my flask app is :

```
name: Flask app test

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.9"]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi

    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        pip install flake8
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics --verbose --exit-zero

    - name: Set up Flask configuration
      run: |
        export FLASK_APP=seoulbike_app.py
        export FLASK_ENV=testing

    - name: Run tests with pytest and coverage
      run: |
        python -m pip install pytest pytest-cov
        python -m pytest tests/ --verbose --cov=seoulbike_app --ignore-errors
```

By the way the pytest work fine in pycharm.

Comment: i'm having a very similar error with exit code 30 after github actions runs. did you ever figure out the cause?